# Explicit Recursion for Determining If Duplicates in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, list-comprehension

This is a small part of a tutorial assignment where we have been asked to define a function firstly using a list comprehension and then using explicit recursion.

> 3. Using a list comprehension, define a function
>
> duplicated :: Eq a => a -­‐> [a] -­‐> Bool
>
> that takes a list element and a list and returns True if there is more than one copy of the list element in the list. For example:
>
> duplicated 10 [1,2,11,11] = False
>
> duplicated 10 [1,2,10,11] = False
>
> duplicated 10 [1,2,10,10] = True

For this I have the code of:

```
duplicated::Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
duplicated n xs = length[x | x <- xs, x == n] > 1
```

But no matter how I seem to attack this, I can't figure out a way to do this with explicit recursion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how to do it using explicit recursion:

```hs
duplicated :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
duplicated _ []     = False
duplicated n (x:xs) = callback n xs
    where callback  = if x == n then elem else duplicated
```

Here's how it works:

1. If the list is empty then it means that we haven't found even one element `n` in the list. Hence, we return `False`.
2. Otherwise, if the current element of the list is `n` then it means that we found one element `n`. Hence we return `elem n xs` which checks whether `n` is in `xs` as well.
3. Otherwise, we recursively call `duplicated n xs`.

Hope that helps.